# How to display expandable method stacks list with sortable columns (like measured call time, count...)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, report

I barely used windows forms before so I don't know where to look. Are there any easy ways to accomplish something like this?
[image: Profiler screen from Unity3D]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mimick the overall structure with a TreeView pretty easily:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, you could build it as a web page (if you prefer web development or want to have the data more portable) and load it in a Browser object.

[The MSDN Documentation for TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: How can I add columns to the TreeView?

Answer (score 0):

Standard TreeView can't do this job. I used http://sourceforge.net/p/treeviewadv/code/HEAD/tree/